# Ember - Getting started guide: DISPLAYING MODEL DATA

Tags: ember.js

I'm going over Ember - Getting Started tutorial but I got stuck. Everything was fine until I got to [Displaying-Model-Data](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/displaying-model-data/) section:

First, adding:

```
Todos.TodosRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return Todos.Todo.find();
  }
});
```

to the router.js file results in blank window, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17075482/ember-todos-an-ember-collectionviews-content-must-implement-ember-array?answertab=oldest#tab-top) which helped returning the layout by adding the next line of code before the code above:

```
Todo.TodosController = Em.ArrayController.extend({});
```

Second, as I continue one step forward and try to replace the static index.html with handlebars to make it dynamic (by this code):

```
<ul id="todo-list">
  {{#each controller}}
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" class="toggle">
      <label>{{title}}</label><button class="destroy"></button>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

again my layout disappears and leaving me with a blank window.

I follow this tutorial step-by-step so don't know what could cause that.

(Found other relevant post but nothing was helpful).

Comment: I guess we need to see more of your code on how you have setup things, a jsbin would be great

Comment: Yes, please post a jsbin. I am in the middle of the guide myself, past that step, and everything is working fine. I haven't used Ember since RC2 and am getting caught up.

Comment: You'll want to keep the console window open in Chrome's dev tools. It will show you the actual error happening. Then you can search for that specific error. :)

Answer (score 0):

After a few debug time, I found out what was the problem, but not exactly sure why.

I used handlebars.js (V 1.0.0) as published in the official site handlebarsjs.com (this is the one which also linked by the Ember Getting started guide in the [dependencies section](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/obtaining-emberjs-and-dependencies/)). After replacing it with the one in [cloudflare](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0-rc.3/handlebars.js) the layout was brought back to life.

Hope it will help someone.

p.s: after this change the addition of

```
Todo.TodosController = Em.ArrayController.extend({});
```

is no longer relevant.